# Box2d simulation periodically slows down

Tags: c++, box2d

I have periodical slowness of Box2d simulation which is very strange because:

- I use enough fast PC with i5 CPU, 4GB RAM, ...
- in box2d there are not more than 15 bodies each with one shape attached
- there are no bullets but there are sensors
- box2d velocity iteration is 6, position iteration is 2
- I build my application in release mode
- tried fixed step simulation and also set simulation delta equal to FPS delta

But though the FPS is 60 (very rare 59) and the other motions and animations move smoothly, but anyway some bodies that are Kinematic and I move them with constant speed they are cutting. I mean these bodies don't move smoothly but can hang in one position and immediately change their position to another. What can cause such behavior?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here since you say the simulation is slow, but then you say everything is moving smoothly at 60fps except for some kinematic bodies... this is not the same as 'simulation slows down' so perhaps you could clarify what you mean or change the question title etc. So anyway, you are seeing this behavior even with a constant time step length (eg. world->Step( 1/60.0f, 6, 2) )?

Comment: @iforce2d I guess this problem is because of cocos2d-x 3.0 rendering on Windows. I have not investigated completely the cause, but I will suggest to forget my question, till I will find the reason and post it. Thanks for your response.